# Not equal to performance JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

```
//loop brace start, suppose "i" is counter, will run 20000 times
var spanXId = $('#parentId #demoId'+i).text();
var spanYId = $('#parentId #demoId'+(i+1)).text();
if(spanXId != spanYId){
   //do something
}else{
   //do something
}
//loop brace end
```

The problem is in assignment of span value "**var spanXId = $('#parentId #demoId'+i).text();**" and the != comparison "**spanXId != spanYId"**. It's taking too much time. Any idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: You might start by using the native DOM rather than jQuery. You also probably shouldn't have repeated ids like that - use a class instead, if possible. Post more of the code for a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

`id`  attributes should be unique in your doc, so `$('#parentId #otherid')` should be replaceable by the almost noop `document.getElementById('otherId')`.

Then retrieving the textContent *might* take some time, so you will probably win again a little bit by caching the previous value:

```
var spanXId = document.getElementById('demoId0').textContent,
  spanYId = null;
// start your loop from index 1
for(var i=1; i<length; i++) {
  spanYId = document.getElementById('demoId' + i);
  if(spanXId !== spanYId) // do your stuff
  ...
  spanXId = spanYId; // cache for next iteration
}
```

---

Now, using iterative ids like that might not be the best practice at all, and you might consider using an other selector, like a class.
Then you'd just have to grab the NodeList prior to entering your loop, and iterate this NodeList the same way.

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('#parentId .demo');
var spanXId = spans[0].textContent,
  spanYId = null;
// start your loop from index 1
for(var i=1; i<spans.length; i++) {
  spanYId = spans[i].textContent;
  if(spanXId !== spanYId) // do your stuff
  ...
  spanXId = spanYId; // cache for next iteration
}
```